# Which Qt widget to use for implementing image thumbnail browser (displaying tiles)?

Tags: qt, widget

I'm looking to essentially replicate this:

[image]

What is the most appropriate Qt container widget for displaying my custom widgets containing image+subscript? I'm looking at `QTableView` and it seems to be supposed to have a set number of rows/columns, while I would like my program to change layout depending on window width (so that there is no horizontal scroll), and adding new widget should be done with `addWidget(QWidget * w)`, not `setWidget(int row, int column, QWidget * w)`. Is there a better component for this than QTableView (which requires much coding for my task)?

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution that allows you actually use custom widgets for items ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should use `QListWidget` (or `QListView` and subclass `QAbstractItemModel`)  and set it's **view mode** to `IconMode`.

**Example :**

```
m_listeWidget->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);

m_listeWidget->setIconSize(QSize(200,200));

m_listeWidget->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);

m_listeWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../earth.jpg"),"Earth"));
m_listeWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../tornado.jpg"),"Tornado"));
m_listeWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../ics.jpg"),"Wallpaper"));
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: That indeed works. I wanted to use my own widget as list item, but any working solution is better than any non-working one, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

definitly QTableView,
Using custom itemDelegate to present every block,
implements the custom widget to display the Image and Text Title

Comment: Not QTableWidget/QListWidget? I'm currently trying QListWidget but aving trouble making it display my widgets at all. 
QTableView would mean I have to handle resizes manually to change the number of columns appropriately, seems too much of a work. Also, why do I need a delegate? All I want to do is display static picture+text widgets, Is there no easier way to achieve that?

Comment: The advantage of QTableView is the free to handle the data model and ItemWidget, so nedd your custom implements of datamodel and itemDelegate  class. It seem much work to do,but give you more convenience.By using itemDelegate,you can easy custom browser sytle and title style ,and so on. I did this Myself in my app.