# Qt list of images

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.8

I am looking for an efficient way to view a list of thumbnails of *jpeg*s in Qt 5.8 (possibly several thousands).

My current approach is to use a `QListWidget` (see below, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114737/which-qt-widget-to-use-for-implementing-image-thumbnail-browser-displaying-tile)). This turns out to be way too slow as it takes forever to assemble, even for a few images.

I am looking:

1. To understand why my current approach is so slow.
2. For a more efficient approach, which still requires only little code by relying as much as possible on Qt's features.

**Current approach:**

```
ui->listWidget->setViewMode  (QListWidget::IconMode);
ui->listWidget->setIconSize  (QSize(200,200)       );
ui->listWidget->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust  );

for ( auto &i : files ) 
  ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(i),i));
```

*(whereby `files` is of the `std::vector<QString>` type)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution might be to create a simple class that inherits from `QListWidgetItem` and fixes up the thumbnails on demand.  You could try something like (note: untested)...

```
class thumbnail_item: public QListWidgetItem {
  using super = QListWidgetItem;
public:
  explicit thumbnail_item (const QString &filename)
    : super(filename)
    {}
  virtual QVariant data (int role) const override
    {
      if (role == Qt::DecorationRole) {
        QIcon i = super::icon();
        if (i.isNull()) {

          /*
           * The existing thumbnail (if any) is empty so create one
           * from the file name and use it -- remembering to call
           * setIcon so we don't need to go through all this again
           * next time.
           */
          i = QIcon(data(Qt::DisplayRole));
          setIcon(i);
        }
        return(i);
      }
      return(super::data(role));
    }
};
```

You still need the loop to create an item for each file but at least it defers the thumbnail construction.

A more elegant solution would probably involve using fully separated model and view objects with a custom [proxy model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html) performing the thumbnail generation and caching.

Answer (score 1):

I have low rep to comment on G.M.'s answer, so here is my addition:

The initialisation may take long time due to 2 reasons:

1. The access to image files and their decoding can take up significant time. It is nice to have some buffering/precaching or defering, as G.M. suggested.
2. I believe, images are loaded "as is" (in high resolution), but resized to tiny resolution for thumbnail view inside QIcon. This can be optimised away by using [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) class for image reading, specifically its method `setScaledSize(const QSize &size)`.